# Do I need anything between my Raspberry Pi, Orin Nano and Power Bank to protect my RPi and Orin Nano?

Tags: raspberry-pi, power, jetson

I am a beginner and am learning by building a 4-wheel mobile robot. I plan to use Li-ion power banks to power my Raspberry Pi and Orin Nano. Do I need any protection between the power bank and the orin nano to protect the orin nano?

The power banks are directly plugged into the usual power inputs of the Pi (USB-C) and Jetson Orin Nano (Power Jack).

The Arduino will be connected and powered by the PI through USB.

[image]

Comment: How are you connecting power to the Jetson and Pi? Are the power banks plugged into the usual power inputs of the Pi (USB-C) and Jetson (power jack), or directly to the 5V rails of the respective GPIO? Also, how is the Arduino being powered. From the image it seems that the Arduino being indirectly powered from the USB port of the Pi? And again, how is the power being applied to the Arduino (via the jack, USB port or the power pins on the header pins)? Your image and description aren't clear. Please [edit] your question and clarify these points (and **not** in the comments).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions to edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are powering the Orin Nano via the micro-USB port on the developer kit, then you are interfacing with some built-in power protection (up to a point, I have managed to fry these dev kits by accidentally doubling their input voltage). If you are powering via the GPIO rails, you are likely bypassing that protection. I've lost more than a few Pi's doing that...

With a bit of care you'll likely be fine, but if you're still worried, there's no harm in adding a simply voltage protection circuit. These are pretty easy to make, and there's [plenty of cheap solutions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516105/cost-effective-way-to-protect-circuit-from-overvoltage).

Comment: Right now, I plan to directly connect the power banks to the USB-C of the Pi and to the power jack of the Orin Nano.